# How can I extract symbols defined in a jar file using Delphi?

Tags: java, delphi, jar, extract, decompiler

I have a java jar file consists of some classes that each class has some variables, constants, functions,...

I want to extract the name of these classes, variables, constants, functions and function parameters in my Delphi program.

A work like that [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) does. How can I do this? Is there any java sdk command line to do this  ?

Comment: Wait, just to get that clear...you want to decompile Java-Bytecode to Delphi?

Comment: decompile from an programming language to another...I don't think you can do this.

Comment: It looks like Vahid just wants to enumerate the symbols in the JAR file

Comment: I just want to make simple IDE, and I need to show users contentes of imported class. (Like any IDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Emil M. Santos* has done the job for you.

He is the author of **Class Explorer** : an utility for browsing the low-level contents of a Java compiled class file (.class).

[image]
<sub>(source: [codexterity.com](http://www.codexterity.com/images/classexp_shot1.gif))</sub>

You can grab its (Delphi for sure) source code [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20060505052750/http://www.codexterity.com:80/download/classexp_src.zip).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, It looks good, but I can't download it! The link is broken, Do you have another link to it?

Comment: You are welcome. At your request, I can send it to you as an attached file by email.

Comment: You can try again, http://www.codexterity.com/ just appeared to be temporarily down. If you can see the screenshot in the post, everything is OK again.

Comment: Thanks, I can see screenshot now and i can download it.

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote a class-file parser for Delphi. You can find it here:

http://essmodel.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/essmodel/essmodel/Integrator/CodeIO/JavaClass/

It is from 2004 but should still work unless the class-file format has changed considerably since then.

The parser is part of the freeware tool [ESS-Model](http://essmodel.sourceforge.net/) that creates static class diagrams.

Note that the parser works on class-files only. If you want to parse jar-files you need to first unzip the jar-file and extract the containing class-files (a jar-file is just a standard zip-file with the ".jar" extension).

Comment: @Vahid: I strongly recommend you to download the **ESS-Model** and harness it, there is no need for other demo app. I've used it in the past and were satisfied.

Comment: @Vahid: Yes, you can download ESS-Model from the link above. It is just a small exe-file that does not require installation. Then just use File - Open to open a class-file to see how it works. uJavaClassImport.pas is the source that reads the class-file and builds up an object model from it.